# Spring: Return JSON response From A Java Bean

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I'm new to springs and I wondering if I can return the contents of a Java Bean as a `JSON` response. Basically, I would have a class `XYZ`,

```
public class XYZ {
    private String name,
    private String email,
    //Setters and getters...
}
```

I was wondering if I can get a response which has

```
{name: 'Something', email: 'something@somethingelse.com'}
```

without any manual processing. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I have achieved the same using DWR. Try to analyze that option

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are plenty of libraries out there for json conversion. You can use [Jackson](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonHome) which is supported by Spring MVC.

```
XYZ obj = /*instance*/;
ObjectMapper converter = new ObjectMapper();
System.out.println(converter.writeValueAsString(obj));
```

Answer (score 4):

Spring `@ResponseBody` is used to return json automatically.

```
@ResponseBody    
public XYZ response() {
    XYZ xyz = new XYZ();
    xyz.setName("name");
    xyz.setEmail("email@com");
    return xyz
}
```

You should add jackson to webapp runtime classpath.

Comment: NB you have to have at least one field+getter/setter or you'll get " No converter found for return value of type: class ..."

Answer (score 3):

We use [fastjson](https://github.com/alibaba/fastjson) to JSONize java beans. It's fast and convenient.

```
public @ResponseBody
String showLesson() {
    Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    return JSON.toJSONString(map);
}
```